# Bootstrap 3 carousel with 6 items not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been using [**this**](http://www.bootply.com/M4ar8XLItz#) solution for a 6 item carousel.

This works well in Dreamweaver but when previewed or published online the effect of advancing by one item is not right. Although it does advance by one item, it slides all items previous to that also.

Take a look at [**this**](http://businessinoxford.com/new/index.html) link, slider is at the bottom of the page.

If anyone has run into issues similar, please point me in the right direction.

I have tried really hard to fix the issue. The only thing I can think of is that it's not responding to a md or lg screen size as you can recreate the problem in the original Bootply example by messing with screen widths after the xs sm @media queries.

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-control                    { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  100%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -100%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -50%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.66666667%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.66666667%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -16.66666667%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/7.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/8.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/9.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="images/logos/6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your problem is that example from JSFiddle uses Bootstrap 3.1.0. In your site you use newer version (3.3.5) which has different styles for carousel (for example translate3d instead of left property).

Comment: @makshh The same effect is occurring in the code snippet in the question which is using Bootstrap 3.3.5.

Comment: @Marcelo BS3.3.5 - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGJZXY, BS3.1.0 - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BobgYm - same code - different effect

Comment: @makshh It looks like it is using translate only on webkit browsers. When viewed in Firefox/IE it uses the left positioning. So it looks like he will also need to use the older version of Bootstrap if he wants to use this approach and also support Chrome/Safari.

Comment: @Marcelo yes this is it but I'm surprised it doesn't work on Firefox which supports translate3d property. It seems that Firefox ignores `@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)`

Comment: @makshh Yes, it's odd to be sure. I went ahead and added the information you provided to the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your input, really appreciate it. Managed to get it working on BS3.2.0. Anything above though causes problems. I see this as only a temporary fix though. With BS4 around the corner, an updated solution would be best. I'll keep any eye out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that both your CSS selectors from your custom CSS and Bootstrap's are both the same level of specificity. Because of this the CSS which is included last will have precedence. If this is Bootstrap, the custom CSS will be overridden and your slider will not behave the way you desire.

To ensure that the custom CSS has priority you can make its selectors more specific. In the example below, I have done so by adding an additional `.carousel` to each selector.

More info on CSS selector specificity can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Additionally, as makshh pointed out, the approach you linked is using an older version of Bootstrap (3.1.0) than the one you are using on your site (3.3.5). The new bootstrap handles carousels differently than the previous version in certain browsers. If you want to support webkit browsers, you will need to either use an older version of Bootstrap or adjust the solution based on the new CSS Bootstrap 3.3.5 is using.

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -100%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -100%;
  }
  .carousel .active > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel .active > div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel .active > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel .active > div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel .active > div:first-child + div {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -16.66666667%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -16.66666667%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```